# How can I convert this query in to CakePHP query?

Tags: php, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-2.6

How can I convert this query into a CakePHP query?

```
SELECT COUNT(invoices.id) FROM invoices,sales 
WHERE invoices.id=sales.invoice_id AND to_id='13' AND is_updated='0' 
GROUP BY invoice_id
```

I have two controllers and two models, invoices and sales.

Comment: please explain which is primary and foreign key in both tables

Comment: i am sorry i just forgot to add foreign key retaliation ,in sales table there is a invoice_id  that relate to invoice table primary key 'id'

Comment: @DebasishSahoo what version of CakePHP are you using as that makes a big difference!

Comment: When you're posting a question and expecting people to help you out, you're supposed to provide adequate details like 1. CakePHP version 2. Model associations(if any) you have specified 3. What you've tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: cake php  version 2.6.4 and there is no model associations ,

Comment: i am very sorry i am new in stackover flow and this my 1st qustion @ Object Manipulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aggregate functions like `COUNT`, you need to create virtual field.

```
$this->Invoice->virtualFields['total'] = 'COUNT(`Invoice`.`id`)';

$result = $this->Invoice->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('Invoice.total'),
  'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'sales',
            'alias' => 'Sale',
            'type'  => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Invoice.id = Sale.invoice_id',
            )
        )
    ),
  'conditions' => array(
     'to_id' => 13,
     'is_updated' => 0 
  ),
  'group' => array('Sale.invoice_id')
));

pr($result); // Check your result
```

Use the following links as references:

[Joining tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)

[Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

[Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Cake's Cookbook solution:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements